# Generating JWT and getting access token for google API

Tags: bash, curl, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-sheets-api

I want to automate the process of grabbing some data from a private google sheet. For this I have planned to use `service account` from google developer console.
While creating a service account, I have generated the key.json file and downloaded it.
According to the official documentation,

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}.
{
"iss":"761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
"aud":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"exp":1328554385,
"iat":1328550785
}.
[signature bytes]
```

Since I am writing bash script,

```
#!/bin/bash
#

epoch_now=$(date +%s)
echo $epoch_now
epoch_expire=$((epoch_now+3600))
echo $epoch_expire

secret='-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----SOME_KEY-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'

base64_encode()
{
    declare input=${1:-$(</dev/stdin)}
    # Use `tr` to URL encode the output from base64.
    printf '%s' "${input}" | base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\n'
}

json() {
    declare input=${1:-$(</dev/stdin)}
    printf '%s' "${input}" | jq -c .
}


HEADER='{"alg": "RS256","typ": "JWT"}'
PAYLOAD="{\"iss\": \"google-sheet@final-excel.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",
\"scope\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly\",
\"aud\": \"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",
\"iat\": ${epoch_now},
\"exp\": ${epoch_expire}}"

header_base64=$(echo "${HEADER}" | json | base64_encode)
payload_base64=$(echo "${PAYLOAD}" | json | base64_encode)

header_payload=$(echo "${header_base64}.${payload_base64}")
```

Now I am having the file safe base64 encoded header and payloads. I just want to know how the signature should be. And also the curl request which can be used to get the access token with the obtained JWT.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309)?

Comment: This is not for the service account. This is used to get the access token using OAuth2.0 credentials.

Comment: There are two more steps. 1) Sign the JWT using the service account private key. Note that your header does not include the kid, which is required to look up the public key. 2) Exchange the signed JWT for an access token. I wrote several articles on how to do this on my personal blog site.

Comment: Can you please let me know those blogs written by you?